# Including header files of base-classes and sub-classes (derived classes) correctly?

Tags: c++, class, subclass, derived-class

Lets say I have 2 base classes, Base1 and Base2.

```
// Base1.h
#ifndef BASE1_H
#define BASE1_H
#include "Base2.h"

class Base2;

class Base1 {
    ...
    void func(Base2* b);
    virtual void subfunc(Base2* b) = 0;
    ...
};
#endif



// Base2.h
#ifndef BASE2_H
#define BASE2_H
#include "Base1.h"

class Base1;

class Base2 {
    ...
    void func(Base1 *b);
    virtual void subfunc(Base1* b) = 0;
    ...
};
#endif
```

and I include each other's header file in each header file since **Base1** has functions that has **Base2** as parameter and **Base2** has functions that has **Base1** as parameter.

Then lets say I have 5 subclasses (derived classes) for both **Base1** and **Base2**;

*Base1_Sub1, Base1_Sub2, Base1_Sub3, Base1_Sub4, Base1_Sub5* for **Base1**
*Base2_Sub1, Base2_Sub2, Base2_Sub3, Base2_Sub4, Base2_Sub5* for **Base2**.

I want to be able to have 5 derived classes of **Base1** as parameter of class function in, lets say **Base2_Sub1**.

```
// Base2_Sub1.h
#ifndef BASE2_SUB1_H
#define BASE2_SUB1_H
#include "Base2.h"
// What else to include!?

class Base2_Sub1 : public Base2 {
    ...
    void subfunc(Base1_Sub1 *b);
    void subfunc(Base1_Sub2 *b);
    void subfunc(Base1_Sub3 *b);
    void subfunc(Base1_Sub4 *b);
    void subfunc(Base1_Sub5 *b);
    ...
};
#endif
```

In what file should *Base1_Sub1*.h to *Base1_Sub5*.h be included?
I also need subclasses of **Base2** (such as *Base2_Sub1*) to have subclasses of **Base1** as function parameter the same way.

I found it extremely confusing to include these headers correctly and I have no idea how. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can avoid including headers by introducing a forward declaration, you do not need to include the header. Both your `Base1.h` and `Base2.h` headers provide good examples: `Base1` can compile with only a forward declaration of `Base2`, because it uses only pointers to `Base2`; same goes for `Base2`'s use of `Base1` pointers. Therefore, the mutual inclusions can be safely removed.

> In what file should `Base1_Sub1.h` to `Base1_Sub5.h` be included?

The inclusion would be mandatory in their corresponding `Base1_Sub1.cpp` to `Base1_Sub5.cpp`. Other cpp files should include them as necessary.

> I also need subclasses of `Base2` (such as `Base2_Sub1`) to have subclasses of `Base1` as function parameter the same way.

As far as header files including header files go, if headers for your subclasses can be defined using pointers to `Base1` and `Base2`, do not include headers at all. This will shrink the time it takes to compile your code.

Of course you need to include headers for classes that you instantiate, and for classes on which you call member functions or access their data members.

Comment: Thank you men, the including must be done in the .cpp files after using  forward declaration in .h, it tooks me 2 or 3 hours to solve it.hamdo ALLAH